# Gitlab not backing up to s3. Where can I find logs?

Tags: docker, logging, gitlab, s3cmd

I am currently trying to migrate our old [sameersbn/gitlab:12.1.6](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab) installation to a new Gitlab instance set up with the [helm chart](https://docs.gitlab.com/charts/).

The easiest way seems to enable the s3 backup capability on the old installation, connect the new instance to the same s3 and restore it from there.

Currently I am stuck with correctly configuring the old installation. I set a bunch of [environment variables](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab/blob/12.1.6/README.md#available-configuration-parameters) on the docker container and expected this to work out of the box.

```
-e "AWS_BACKUPS=true" \
-e "AWS_BACKUP_MULTIPART_CHUNK_SIZE=500" \
-e "AWS_BACKUP_ACCESS_KEY_ID=minio" \
-e "AWS_BACKUP_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=minio" \
-e "AWS_BACKUP_REGION=main" \
-e "AWS_BACKUP_BUCKET=gitlab-backup-storage" \
-e "AWS_BACKUP_ENDPOINT=https://minio.com"
```

But it doesn't. I couldn't see any errors in the docker logs, so I checked the `/var/log/gitlab` folder with no success. Some other logs, but none indicate whether the backup started/succeeded/failed and I cannot see any backups in the s3 bucket.

Now I don't know where to look and what to check.

Comment: Have you inputted your "actual" values for Key/Secret/Region/Bucket/Endpoint values? That endpoint is for sure good?

Comment: Yes, I use the same setup/s3cfg in the Gitlab instance installed via helm chart and I can restore manually uploaded backups with it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to manually start the backup process by running

```sh
/home/git/gitlab/bin/rake gitlab:backup:create --trace
```

inside the docker container. You then get an output which states what the problem is.

I had a similar problem and could not upload to wasabi. Turns out my configuration, especially my endpoint was wrong.
This is the config I am successfully using:

```yaml
    - AWS_BACKUPS=true
    - AWS_BACKUP_REGION=eu-central-1
    - AWS_BACKUP_ENDPOINT=https://s3.eu-central-1.wasabisys.com
    - AWS_BACKUP_ACCESS_KEY_ID=some-id
    - AWS_BACKUP_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=some-secret
    - AWS_BACKUP_BUCKET=gitlab-backups
```